# Align Header and Math in Tabular

Tags: tables, math-mode, horizontal-alignment

I am trying to align math in a tabular on the `=` sign. This works fine but I would like to have a header centered above that math. So far I have this which does not look good:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand*{\pdiff}[2]{\mathop{}\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c r @{\(=\)} l c c}
  \toprule
  Variable & Partial &&  Sensitivity coefficient & Contribution to error in g\\
  \midrule
  \(m_1\) & \(\pdiff{g}{m_1}\) & \(-\frac{4dm_2}{t^2(m_1-m_2)^2}\) & -409.7 &
    -0.4097\\
  \(m_2\) & \(\pdiff{g}{m_2}\) & \(\frac{4dm_1}{t^2(m_1-m_2)^2}\) & 441.8 &
    0.4418\\
  \(d\) & \(\pdiff{g}{d}\) & \(\frac{2(m_1+m_2)}{t^2(m_1-m_2)}\) & 5.889 &
    0.0177\\
  \(t\) & \(\pdiff{g}{t}\) & \(-\frac{4d(m_1+m_2)}{t^3(m_1-m_2)}\) & -5.677 &
    -2.2708\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You do not define `\pdiff`, hence your code does not compile

Comment: @yo' Made my MWE too minimal. Sorry :)

Comment: Thanks :) I wonder what `\mathop{}` is there for, but ok.

Comment: @yo' I'm not very good with commands. I was modifying an old answer.

Comment: Well, I would go simply with `\newcommand\pdiff[2]{\frac{\partial#1}{\partial#2}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand\pdiff[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c r @{\({}={}\)} l S S}
  \toprule
  \bfseries Variable & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Partial} &  {\bfseries Sensitivity} & {\bfseries Contribution}
  \\
  &\multicolumn{2}{c}{} & {\bfseries coefficient} & {\bfseries to error in $g$}\\
  \midrule
  \(m_1\) & \(\pdiff{g}{m_1}\) & \(-\frac{4dm_2}{t^2(m_1-m_2)^2}\) & -409.7 &
    -0.4097\\
  \(m_2\) & \(\pdiff{g}{m_2}\) & \(\frac{4dm_1}{t^2(m_1-m_2)^2}\) & 441.8 &
    0.4418\\
  \(d\) & \(\pdiff{g}{d}\) & \(\frac{2(m_1+m_2)}{t^2(m_1-m_2)}\) & 5.889 &
    0.0177\\
  \(t\) & \(\pdiff{g}{t}\) & \(-\frac{4d(m_1+m_2)}{t^3(m_1-m_2)}\) & -5.677 &
    -2.2708\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Note the changes:

- `@{\(=\)}` to `@{\({}={}\)}` to get the proper spacing
- usage of multicolumn
- boldface header (not necessary)
- usage of `S` column from `siunitx` for numerical data
- usage of `{...}` in headers to `S` columns (necessary to suppress the siunitx formatting)
- long column headers split in two lines

Comment: would be helped with a little extra space between the rows.

Answer (score 1):

Here, I use TABstacks to set each column, which allows me to get various alignments... not only in the equation column, but also for the decimal columns, too.  Additionally, I set the baseline-skip of the stacks to 2.5 the `\normalbaselineskip`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\newcommand*{\pdiff}[2]{\mathop{}\dfrac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
\begin{document}
\setstackgap{L}{2.5\normalbaselineskip}
\stackMath
\setstackEOL{\cr}
\savestack\colA{\Longstack{m_1\cr m_2\cr d\cr t}}
\savestack\colB{\alignLongstack{%
\pdiff{g}{m_1} =& -\dfrac{4dm_2}{t^2(m_1-m_2)^2} \cr
\pdiff{g}{m_2} =& \dfrac{4dm_1}{t^2(m_1-m_2)^2} \cr
\pdiff{g}{d} =& \dfrac{2(m_1+m_2)}{t^2(m_1-m_2)} \cr
\pdiff{g}{t} =& -\dfrac{4d(m_1+m_2)}{t^3(m_1-m_2)}
}}
\savestack\colC{\alignLongstack{-409.&7\cr441.&9\cr5.&889\cr-5.&677}}
\savestack\colD{\alignLongstack{-0.&4097\cr0.&4418\cr0.&0177\cr-2.&2708}}
\begin{tabular}{c c c c}
  \toprule
  Variable & Partial &  Sensitivity & Contribution to \\
&& coefficient&error in g\\
  \midrule
\colA&\colB&\colC&\colD\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For my exercises and for see similar, however slightly different approach how to typeset tables with math contents:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{array,booktabs,makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
    \usepackage{siunitx}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{center}% if table is in float environment, than replace with \centering
\begin{tabular}{>{$\displaystyle}c<{$} 
                >{$\displaystyle}r<{$} 
                    @{\;} 
                >{$\displaystyle}l<{$} S S}
    \toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\thead{Variable}}  
    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Partial}} 
            &   {\thead{Sensitivity\\ 
                        coefficient}}  
                        &   {\thead{Contribution\\
                                   to error in $g$}} \\
  \midrule
m_1 &   \pardif{g}{m_1} =
        &   -\frac{4dm_2}{t^2(m_1-m_2)^2}             
            &   -409.7  &  -0.4097                  \\ 
    \addlinespace
m_2 & \pardif{g}{m_2} =
        &   \frac{4dm_1}{t^2(m_1-m_2)^2}
            & 441.8     &   0.4418                  \\
    \addlinespace
d   &   \pardif{g}{d} = 
        &   \frac{2(m_1+m_2)}{t^2(m_1-m_2)} 
            &   5.889   &   0.0177                  \\
    \addlinespace
t   &   \pardif{g}{t} = 
        &  -\frac{4d(m_1+m_2)}{t^3(m_1-m_2)} 
            & -5.677    &  -2.2708                  \\
  \bottomrule

\end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    \end{document}
```

For column headers I use `\thead` from `makecell` and by it merge the first two table rows in one. I also change the way to typeset math, to me is now more beautiful ... I slightly simplify new command for partial differentiation, so I change it name. For increasing distance between rows I use `\addlinespace` from `booktabs` package. Result is:

[image]